# In definition of \pgfpicture why \pgf@picmaxx and \pgf@picmaxy are negative and what exactly this 16000pt value?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, dimensions

The definition of `pgfpicture` macro from `pgfcorescopes.code.tex`

```
\def\pgfpicture{%
  \begingroup%
    \pgfpicturetrue%
    \global\advance\pgf@picture@serial@count by1\relax%
    \edef\pgfpictureid{pgfid\the\pgf@picture@serial@count}%
    \let\pgf@nodecallback=\pgfutil@gobble%
    \pgf@picmaxx=-16000pt\relax%
    \pgf@picminx=16000pt\relax%
    \pgf@picmaxy=-16000pt\relax%
    \pgf@picminy=16000pt\relax%
    \pgf@relevantforpicturesizetrue%
    \pgf@resetpathsizes%
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar\bgroup\pgf@oldpicture\pgf@picture}
```

What represent this value of `16000pt` and why is used for `\pgf@picmaxx` and `\pgf@picmaxy` with negative sign?

Comment: Probably (just a guess) it initialises the picture with the largest possible size (almost), since TeX's maximum allowed dimension is about `16384 pt`, then shrinks as you put things in the picture.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik and why `\pgf@picmaxx`  and `\pgf@picmaxy` are  negative ?

Comment: Because if you have `-infinity` (in TeX that's `-16384 pt`) for `\pgf@picmaxy`, then `max(\pgf@picmaxy,<any value>)` will always return `<any value>` and you will always have the correct `\pgf@picmaxy`.  If it were initialised as zero that would be wrong for negative values, if if it were `+infinity` you'd need to test every time.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik can you add an answer for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value 16000 pt is close to the maximum dimension allowed by TeX, 2¹⁴ pt = 16384 pt (actually it's 16384 pt − 1 sp = 16383.99998 pt), so you can count it as (close to) infinity, as far as TeX knows.

It is common practice in programming, when trying to determine the minimum or maximum value of some set of values incrementally, to start with −∞ for the maximum, and +∞ for the minimum.  This is so because if you start with (for example) zero for the maximum, you will have a wrong result if your number happens to be negative.  Starting at −∞ (or as reasonably close as you can get) you can for sure know that your number is bigger than that, and vice-versa for the minimum.

If the language you are using has a `max` function you can just do `curr_max = max(curr_max,<any value>)`, and if `curr_max` is −∞, whatever `<any value>` happens to be will give the right answer.

Since TeX doesn't have a builtin `max` function, PGF does:

```tex
\ifdim \pgf@x>\pgf@picmaxx
  \pgf@picmaxx=\pgf@x
\fi
```

which is roughly what a `max` function would do.